Why leave the variable at the end of the with statement?
I am trying to make sense of the why you would just write a particular variable at the end of the with statement ?
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'coder2j',
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG(
    default_args=default_args,
    dag_id="dag_with_cron_expression_v04",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 11, 1),
    schedule_interval='0 3 * * Tue-Fri'
) as dag:
    task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        bash_command="echo dag with cron expression!"
    )
    task1 # What does this mean ?

This example is taken from here.
Why just leave the task1 variable at the end ?

Ask the author. There is no reason, and variable task1 with the assignment could just be removed.

As an expression statement, the only thing this does is perform a name lookup, whose only possible side effect is a NameError, which clearly will not happen. Based on the other examples in the repository, I'd say it was a copy-paste artifact that wasn't cleaned up, or an incomplete example where an anticipated task2 was never added.

@chepner Weirdly, the author also does this in the youtube video from which he explains another example: https://youtu.be/K9AnJ9_ZAXE?t=2024

My only other guess is that this is a stylistic convention for uniformity between examples. (Every with statement defines one or more tasks, then combines them. If there is just one task, the trivial combination is still typed.) (I don't think anything is doing weird inspect tricks that expects such a trivial combination  to appear in order for something to happen.)

(Or, without slogging through the rest of the video, this is just in anticipation of adding a second task later.)

Maybe the code was run in IDLE in which case task1 at the end does have meaning - i.e., it will be (implicitly) printed

This could be stylistic. I find out many airflow writers first create all tasks, then in a second part of the script, do task1 >> task2 dependencies of all tasks. Here it serves to show, there is one task, depends on nothing. I prefer BashOperator() >> BashOperator to do it inline when possible.

You are right, there is no reason for it. Also variable task1 with the assignment could just be removed. Just:
with DAG(
    default_args=default_args,
    dag_id="dag_with_cron_expression_v04",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 11, 1),
    schedule_interval='0 3 * * Tue-Fri'
) as dag:
    BashOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        bash_command="echo dag with cron expression!"
    )

